# How to sort the output of difference between two sets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set

I have two sets `a` and `b` and I am printing the difference between these two sets as shown below. The issue I am facing is output is not coming in a sorted way as shown in "Actual output". I need output in such a way that lines that have differences in both the files should be after each other as shown in "Expected output".

```
a = {
    'Jane Lee|248 Another St.|Boston|US|02130|4535353535.35353535353',
    'Jim Smth|123 Any Street|Boston|US|02134',
    'Name|Address|City|Country|Pinode'
}

b = {
    'Jane Lee|248 Another St.|Boston|US|02130|4535353535.3535355353',
    'Jim Smith|123 Any Stret|Boston|US|02134',
    'Name|Address|Cty|Country|Pincode'
}

res_dict = defaultdict(list)
diff = ([('ua.csv,' + i) if i in a else ('pr.csv,' + i) if i in b else ''
         for i in list(a ^ b)])

if diff == []:
    print('Great!!! There are no differences')
else:
    print('\n'.join(diff))
```

Actual output:

```
ua.csv,Name|Address|City|Country|Pinode
ua.csv,Jane Lee|248 Another St.|Boston|US|02130|4535353535.35353535353
pr.csv,Name|Address|Cty|Country|Pincode
pr.csv,Jim Smith|123 Any Stret|Boston|US|02134
pr.csv,Jane Lee|248 Another St.|Boston|US|02130|4535353535.3535355353
ua.csv,Jim Smth|123 Any Street|Boston|US|02134
```

Expected output: Need output in such a way that lines that have differences in both the files should be after each other like below:

```
ua.csv,Name|Address|City|Country|Pinode
pr.csv,Name|Address|Cty|Country|Pincode

ua.csv,Jane Lee|248 Another St.|Boston|US|02130|4535353535.35353535353
pr.csv,Jane Lee|248 Another St.|Boston|US|02130|4535353535.3535355353

pr.csv,Jim Smith|123 Any Stret|Boston|US|02134
ua.csv,Jim Smth|123 Any Street|Boston|US|02134
```

Comment: Are you aware that sets in Python are unordered? Meaning they cannot store the order of their elements.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, sets are unordered. They do not store information about which element is first, second, etc. You can picture it as a heap of fruits - you can't tell which fruit is in which position, you can just say if a banana is there or compare the heap with another heap to check if they contain different fruits.

For this reason, an implementation using sets won't work, you will have to use some structures that are ordered, that keep information about the order of their elements (e.g. a list).

Comment: I thought may be output can be sorted if not sets so posted this one

Comment: You can try to implement it using lists instead of sets and then comparing each line in the first list with the corresponding line in the second list. You will, however, need to figure out how to solve the case when there isn't the same amount of lines. Just a simple new empty line in one of the lists could suddenly make you compare lines that at first weren't meant to be compared.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the output by supplying a function via a keyword argument named `key=` to extract a comparison key from elements when calling the built-in [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function. In thus case all the callback function does is split the string on the first comma they all contain and returns the substring following it.

```
a = {
    'Jane Lee|248 Another St.|Boston|US|02130|4535353535.35353535353',
    'Jim Smth|123 Any Street|Boston|US|02134',
    'Name|Address|City|Country|Pinode'
}

b = {
    'Jane Lee|248 Another St.|Boston|US|02130|4535353535.3535355353',
    'Jim Smith|123 Any Stret|Boston|US|02134',
    'Name|Address|Cty|Country|Pincode'
}

diff = [('ua.csv,' + i) if i in a else ('pr.csv,' + i) if i in b else ''
         for i in list(a ^ b)]

if diff == []:
    print('Great!!! There are no differences')
else:
    diff = sorted(diff, key=lambda v: v.split(',', maxsplit=1)[1])
    print('\n'.join(diff))
```

Output:

```
ua.csv,Jane Lee|248 Another St.|Boston|US|02130|4535353535.35353535353
pr.csv,Jane Lee|248 Another St.|Boston|US|02130|4535353535.3535355353
pr.csv,Jim Smith|123 Any Stret|Boston|US|02134
ua.csv,Jim Smth|123 Any Street|Boston|US|02134
ua.csv,Name|Address|City|Country|Pinode
pr.csv,Name|Address|Cty|Country|Pincode
```